# Renegade Xcode files?

Tags: xcode

I seem to have some files in my Xcode project that I **can't** erase. I've tried right-clicking->deleting, dragging out, Build->Clean, anything I can possibly think of.

[image: It won't go away!]

Any ideas how to get rid of these renegade files?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure in an older version of Xcode you could dig around (**AT YOUR OWN GREAT PERIL!**) inside the .xcodeproj file (show package contents and look in there) and somewhere was an xml file which held everything like that. However, I have just had a quick look and didn't see anything that looked likely. Try grepping the files in there for your rogue filenames and see if anything shows up.

If you don't get anywhere in that route you might be able to trick it by creating those files (or at least files with those names) again, then re-importing / re-deleting them.

Comment: I tried grepping and couldn't find anything.

Unfortunately, what it comes down to is I've never seen a file somehow come **above** the project listing (in my instance, PedalTome).

Comment: I had the exact same issue and I'm sure that's how I fixed it. I can't remember any more details though, I'm really sorry!